# Laravel not saving a field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an application running Laravel 5.3.

I need to make a modification to all records in a table so this is my code:

```
Car::all()->each(function($car){
    $car->created_by = 10;
    $car->updated_by = 15;
    $car->save();
});
```

The problem is that the created_by field is being saved properly but updated_by doesn't. Even if I `dump($car)` previously to the save() line I can see that both fields have been modified. I also added both fields to `$fillable` (I know, this is for mass assignments but just in case..).

Comment: please share your `Model` and if possible the migrations aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. My model is using a trait that everytime the model is updated it saves who made the update in the updated_by field so since I'm executing from the console through a command the first code I posted, the trait is saving that update action and being that no user is logged auth()->user() returns null and this is what is saved. Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: it seems you found the solution. but generally, using the code you posted is not efficient at all. In fact, its not good. However, since what you wanted is resolved then ride on.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than retrieve all cars and loop round them and make thousands of query, you can do the mass update in one query:

```
Car::update(['created_by' => 10, 'updated_by' => 15]);
```

This is simple, clean, more efficient.

If you need more information, please read through [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4) especially about [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Hope it helps.

**Update**

I see that update method cannot be called statically by the model, hence a little hack is to say:

```
Car::where('id', '!=', null)->update(['created_by' => 10, 'updated_by' => 15]);
```

> PS: Beware that your `created_by` or `updated_by` field must not be unique, else it **will** throw some `Integrity constraint violation` error as a result of the query. Of course, no one mass update a unique field.